# How does the ** work while searching for a Path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I didn't find a lot of info about this, as far as I know it matches filenames and directories recursively, but how does it work?

Comment: See [bash globstar matching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching)

Comment: Don't forget to enable it with `shopt -s globstar`. To disable use `shopt -u globstar`

Comment: See [globstar](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) in Greg's wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob-expression `**` is used to match all files **and** zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

This means that it is used in a recursive file-search during path-name expansion patterns on the command line.

Depending on the shell you use, it needs to be enabled. In bash this is done with:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
```

Here are examples:

```
# list all files recursively
$ echo **
# list all files recursively that end with .txt
$ echo **/*.txt
# list all files recursively that are in a subdirectory foo
$ echo **/foo/**
```

Beware that the following pattern does not work recursively `**.txt`. This is just seen as a combination of two single asterisk globs and is identical to `*.txt`.

**Note:** there are subtle differences between bash and zsh, but in general it works the same.